# Tool for Shell systax errors in windows?

Tags: windows, shell

I am writing my shell scripts using notepad++ editor in windows xp but I can not check for systax error in this editor. Is there any tool which can check the syntax of the shell scripts in windows xp?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Shel script editor for windows http://www.editrocket.com/features/shellscript_editor.html

Answer (score 0):

If you mean batch files, then it's getting fairly difficult. My syntax highlighter can show me some things, e.g. using `%f` instead of `%%f` but not much else I could do wrong. That is mostly because the syntax for batch files isn't really described by a formal grammar but instead parsed in a more ad-hoc manner.

Just learn to write correct code, in that case. No editor will be of much help, especially given the subtleties that can arise with batch files. Or do you see the error in the following code?

```
@echo off
for %%x in (World,Moon) do (
    echo Hello %%x :-) - A good morning to you.
)
```